# Why I can't switch to design mode when formatting a column in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2019, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am using Sharepoint 2019 and I would like to do something like this as mentioned in MSDN:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

[image]

And I have a list like this:

[image]

It's a very simple list, what I want to try is:

If customer name = "tester" then change to green color, or else red

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
   "attributes":{
      "class":"=if(@currentField == 'Tester', 'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--blocked') + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
   },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the above code does not have any effect. Later on I searched on the web and found out there's a "format column" button, however, it looks different to me:
[image]

The "Switch to design mode" button is missing:

[image]

Does sharepoint 2019 support this feature? or it only supports static formatting? If I change my code to

```
 {
   "$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType":"div",
   "attributes":{
      "class":"sp-field-severity--good ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
   },
   "children":[
      {
         "elmType":"span",
         "txtContent":"@currentField"
      }
   ]
}
```

It works as expected

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Excel-style expressions begin with an equal (=) sign. This style of expression is only available in SharePoint Online (not SharePoint 2019).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#excel-style-expressions

You need to use basic styled syntax, please refer to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/47ae9f86-1884-49c1-8b84-07168ba4df48/column-formatting-not-working?forum=SP2019

Comment: Thank you this helps I'll add a short explanation to that code

Answer (score 0):

I've made an answer upon Julie's suggestion:

```
{
    "$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
       "elmType":"div",
       "attributes":{
          "class":{
             "operator":"+",
             "operands":[
                {
                   "operator":"?",
                   "operands":[
                      {
                         "operator":"==",
                         "operands":[
                            "@currentField",
                            "Tester"
                         ]
                      },
                      "sp-field-severity--good",
                      {
                         "operator":"?",
                         "operands":[
                            {
                               "operator":"==",
                               "operands":[
                                  "@currentField",
                                  "Test2"
                               ]
                            },
                            "sp-field-severity--warning",
                            "sp-field-severity--blocked"
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                " ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
             ]
          }
       },
       "children":[
          {
             "elmType":"span",
             "txtContent":"@currentField"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Let me explain a little bit on this syntax regarding the "class" attribute:

The operator "+" represents concatenating 2 strings (which are the class names in my case)
The json object inside "operands" is like an iif function

> iif(expression, true, false)

The "operands" syntax in "?" operator is the expression `if current field value equals tester`:

```
{
   "operator":"==",
   "operands":[
      "@currentField",
      "Tester"
   ]
}
```

Next is the true expression: `Put a "sp-field-severity--good" in it`

```
"sp-field-severity--good"
```

And next will be the false expression which is same as the "?" operator same as above

The whole pseudo code will be like:

```
string finalClass = "";
If currentFieldValue == "Tester" Then
    finalClass = "sp-field-severity--good"
Else If currentFieldValue == "Test2" Then
    finalClass = "sp-field-severity--warning"
Else
    finalClass = "sp-field-severity--blocked"
End If

finalClass = finalClass + " ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
```

Please take note that there's a space before "`ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary`" because it's 2 classes
The children attribute is the html code which will be generated in that field

```
   "children":[
      {
         "elmType":"span",
         "txtContent":"@currentField"
      }
   ]
```

So the element will be a "`span`" containing the value of current field
[image]
[image]